# Display GridView inside ExpandableListView for unknown groupCount in Android

Tags: android, gridview, expandablelistview

I'm having a class (***ExpandableListDataClass***) which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

I am calling to ***ExpandableListDataClass*** from an `Activity` like below;

```
ExpandableListDataClass expandableListDataClass = new ExpandableListDataClass(this, categories);
categoryExpandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListDataClass);
```

***categories*** is a String array. That means groupCount of the ***ExpandableListDataClass*** is depend on the ***categories***.
The worst thing is, I am loading a `GridView` for expanding of a group item in `ExpandableListView`. Those `GridView` have different data to show according to the category.

If I use following code inside `getChildView()`, it is perfectly working

```
if(getGroup(groupPosition).toString().equals("ebooks")){
    expandableListInsideGridView.setAdapter(eBooksImageAdapterForExpandableList);
}else if(getGroup(groupPosition).toString().equals("ebrochures")){
    expandableListInsideGridView.setAdapter(eBrochuresImageAdapterForExpandableList);
}
```

But what I want to remove from that is ***eBooksImageAdapterForExpandableList*** and ***eBrochuresImageAdapterForExpandableList***. Because now what I am doing is creating `ArrayList` according to the existing categories.
But when I don't know how many categories/groupCount there are, I can't do that.

Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to find a solution :-)

I will explain it in backwards.

In the `getChildView()` I have to give following line of code

```
expandableListInsideGridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapterForExpandableList(expandableListDataClassContext, eItemThumbCachePathArrayListContainer.get(groupPosition), eItemNamesArrayListContainer.get(groupPosition), eItemUrlArrayListContainer.get(groupPosition)));
```

`getChildView()` is in the ***ExpandableListDataClass*** which extends the `BaseExpandableListAdapter`.

What I had to do is declare an `ArrayList` which contains some other ArraLists of same type. If I explain it more with my code ***eItemThumbCachePathArrayListContainer*** is an `ArrayList` which contains ArrayLists of type String that I want to pass. That is the simple logic I have used and it works for me.